# How do Gold rewards in Smite work?

Tags: smite

I'm pretty new to smite and I don't quite get how the gold reward system works there. Sometimes I feel like I got gold although I didn't lasthit a creep. Also personally I don't find the interface clear when it comes to displaying how much gold you just earned.

So basically My questions are:

- Which actions will get you gold?
- How much gold do they give you?

I'm especially interested in the conquest (Classic 5v5 MOBA) mode.

Comment: Edited answer to add Conquest information!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actions that get you gold:

- Being in the vicinity when a minion or jungle creep dies (I believe it's 50 feet). This method only gets you partial, unless you have [Watcher's gift](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Watcher%27s_Gift)

  - You will **not** get any gold if your defending objectives (towers, phoenix, titan) last hit the minion
- Last hitting a minion gets you an additional 50% bonus
- killing jungle creeps
- destroying objectives (towers, phoenixes, gold fury, Fire Giant). Everyone on the team receives gold regardless of where they are.
- getting a kill assist on a god (damaging, CCing, or "body blocking" counts as assist)
- First Blood (the first god kill of the game) is an additional 200 gold bonus
- getting a kill on a god. the formula for how much you earn per kill is below.

> Base Amount = (150 + (Gold Earned by Victim / 100)) 
>        Level Adjustment = ((enemy level - player level) * .1) This is capped at +/- .6. Total = (Base Amount + (Base Amount * Level
>   Difference Adjustment)) * 1.1 ^ Opponents Kill Streak

In Conquest:

- All gods start with 1500 gold
- towers are 200 gold global, 250 for assist in bringing it down
- phoenixes are 150 global, 200 for assist bringing down
- small jungle fury gives 71 gold (if solo or with [Bumba's mask](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Bumba%27s_Mask))
- large(mid) jungle fury gives 90 gold (again, jungle so if solo or with the Mask)
- jungle buff camps give 91 gold
- gold fury is 300 global
- fire giant is 150 global
- last hit is a 50% bonus added to the "normal" proximity reward
- Archer minions give 18 gold on last hit if solo, 12 proximity.
- Melee minions give 25 gold on last hit if solo, 17 proximity.
- brute minions (big melee guys) give 29 gold if solo, 20 proximity.

When friendly gods are around you the gold reward splits evenly. Example, if you are in the duo lane, archer minions will give 6 gold, but if you or your partner god last hit while you have Watcher's, you will get 9.

The other modes merely scale on this base formula.

There is also options in the game to tweak reward text so it's more clear. The default pops up near your god with pretty small text. God kill rewards will also show up in the chat feed.

Comment: `You will not get any gold if your defending objectives (towers, phoenix, titan) last hit the minion` This is not correct. It does not matter when the tower hit it. It does not have to be a last hit to not receive gold for it.

Comment: What happens when a minion last hits a minion? Do gods still get proximity rewards, or do they count like towers?

Comment: @Annan a minion last hitting another minion gets you the proximity reward.